# Materialize CSS Notification Count Does Not Show Count Numbers

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I am using Materialize CSS for one of my projects. I am trying to show the notification count on an icon. Here is my code:

```
<a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-activates="notification"> <i class="material-icons white-text ">notifications <small class="notification-badge">5</small></i></a>
```

CSS style

```
.notification-badge {
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    top: -20px;
    color: #941e1e;
    background-color: #f5f1f2;
    margin: 0 -.8em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 4px 5px;
}
```

Here is the output I get. Everything is fine except notification count (5) not showing.

[image]

I tried method by davecar21 and changed CSS to below:

```
.notification-badge {
    position: relative;
    right: -20px;
    top: -80px;
    color: #941e1e;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 -.8em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

But now the issue is that dropdown notification list has a space. Check below image. How to solve this?
[image]

Here is my nav code.

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="orange darken-3">

    <div class="nav-wrapper container">

      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">KnowYourGST</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="/blog/">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/qa/">Q&A</a></li>
        <li><a href="/invoice/">Invoicing</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Acts and Law<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/search/"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>

        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-activates="notification"> <i class="material-icons grey-text ">notifications</i><small class="notification-badge">5</small> </a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-activates="profile">Knowyourgst<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="/blog/">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/qa/">Q&A</a></li>
        <li><a href="/invoice/">Invoicing</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Acts and Law<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="/search/"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>

        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="notification">Notification<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="profile">Knowyourgst<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve that issue don't enclose your `.notification-badge` to `.material-icons` because `.notification-badge` will inherit the `.white-text` color.

```
<a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-activates="notification">
  <i class="material-icons white-text ">notifications</i>
  <small class="notification-badge">5</small>
</a>
```

Then add some padding to achieve that badge circle

```
.notification-badge {
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    top: -20px;
    color: #941e1e;
    background-color: #f5f1f2;
    margin: 0 -.8em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

---

> But now the issue is that dropdown notification list has a space.

The reason why this issue is occurs is that you are using `position:relative` to the `notification-badge` this means that it is still occupying space that where it is originated.

What you need to do is add class `notif` to the notification and set its position to absolute;

```
.notif{
  position: absolute;
}
```

.

```
<i class="material-icons grey-text notif">notifications</i>
```

And then set the style of `.notification-badge`

```
.notification-badge {
  position:relative;
  padding:5px 9px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #941e1e;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed few things and got it working. I mean it appears where I want it but now problem is dropdown list has a space. updating question with details.

Comment: @SapnaSharma can you provide that whole code snippet of the navigation bar so that I can be able to help you more. I think there's a related issue in the container.

Comment: @SapnaSharma It's seems that its a position related issue. Please see my updated answer to see the fix.

Comment: If I add notif class and styles. Notification count disappears.

Comment: I works fine in my end. Please see this pen https://codepen.io/deibu21/pen/bLOKwL/

Comment: I believe some sort of issue at my end. Accepting answer as example seems to work.

Comment: I see. Hope you'd be able to fix that issue .. glad to help.